# Docker image disk refreshing forever

Tags: docker, image

I see this page on image section of docker desktop is refreshing, and when i try to pull images of my applications i have the following error:

```
ERROR: pull access denied for invoice, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

even when i do ***docker login*** I have the same error shown!

[image]

help please :)

Comment: can that mean i am running out of memory on my disk memory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a full disk memory, so i only deleted some big files and its back to normal.